# Android Studio does not show detail code. Is there any solution?

Tags: android, kotlin

[image]

Someday, Android IDE start to show code lines like attached picture.
Even though, I click Download Sources, result is same.
It just show /* compiled code */ so, I couldn't see the detail code.

Is there any solution for this?

Comment: Try pressing the control button and then click on the method that you want to see.

Comment: There is a `Download Source` button on the top right, you can download sources using it and then can read the code.